# How to copy and insert row keeping reference for a index like card

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, reference, spreadsheet

I work with a sheet that have rows formatted like cards.

I have to manually change the indexes every time i copy a whole card and insert on anyother empty row.
Also everytime i copy a row and insert below another row.

The indexes are the 1.x 2.x numbers.

I cant come up with a solution to this.

The screenshots are more clear on what i mean.

On this first screenshot you can see the sub-total works fine, i simply get rid of the text and add one (+1)

[image: screenshot1]

On this second screenshot you can see that i copied a new card 3, the subtotal gets changed to 4 immediately but the indexes do not change

[image: screenshot2]

Same problem as i cant figured out a formula that stays there because the cards vary in row sizes **(they can have any number of 4.x rows)**

[image: screenshot3]

I have to work on this format since its my job sheets..

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula can be used to calculate the sub-index:

```
=INDEX(A:A,LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:A9=""),ROW($A$1:A9))+1) & "." & ROW()- LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:A9=""),ROW($A$1:A9))-1
```

There must be at least one blank line before each Card entry (also before the first one)

[image]

**Explanation:**

1. Function `LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:A9=""),ROW($A$1:A9))` finds the last empty row in an range and returns that row number to parameter for `INDEX` function.
2. In the `INDEX` function, I add a one to the row number and find the value for that row in column `A`
3. Then concatenate found value with `.`
4. Then again `LOOKUP` finds last empty row in range and subtracts it from the current row number minus one
5. Then concatenate result with previous string

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfect!!!!
Can you try to explain a little bit how it works? I fiddled with it but its too advanced for me